# Kentico - Setting priority order of document aliases / rewrite rules

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, e-commerce, kentico

I have a Kentico e-commerce website with the following tree structure:

- Products

  - My Category 1 (Category page)

    - My Product 1 (Product page)
    - My Product 2 (Product page)

Categories can be accessed by any combination of the following URL’s:

- /my-category-1/red (Filters)
- /my-category-1/plain/red (Filters)
- /my-category-2/patterned/red/plain (Filters)

This is achieved by setting up a 'route' against the 'My Category 1' category with the path/pattern '/my-category-1/{*categories}'

We also have a requirement to be able to access products via the URL’s

- /my-category-1/my-product-1
- /my-category-2/my-product-2

These pages are never hit however because of the route setup against the category pages.

Does anyone have any advise of how this could be achieved whilst maintaining the desired url structure? I'm trying to avoid a scenario whereby I have to perform a database check of whether a page is a product or not.

Is there anyway to 'prioritise' routing in Kentico?

Answer (score 1):

Your product URL `/my-category-1/my-product-1` falls under `/my-category-1/{*categories}`, so system will always take you to the category page trying to apply some filter. You just need to put different URL templates for those pages, e.g.:

Product page:

```
/product/my-category-1/my-product-1    
/my-category-1/product/my-product-1
```

If don't want to set product page URL like above, you have to URL template for Category with filter, e.g:

```
/my-category-1/filter/{*categories}
```

This is not that much of Kentico problem, but routing. You can get more details on routing [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately however I can't change the URL structure:

/my-category-1/my-product: should redirect to the details page
/my-category-1/red/plain: should redirect to the listings page.

Initial thoughts I had were to check the 'route' is a product - if it is, redirect accordingly but this is a bit hacky and requires a database lookup for every request.